# Install apk programmatically and omit install dialog

Tags: android, android-tv

We have a catalogue of apps and in our main app we want the user to show all other apps we provide and be able for them to install them - **without going through the Google Play store**

The flow would be:

- Select an app in our main app
- APK is downloaded from a remote server (https)
- APK gets installed
- APK gets opened

So far we have been able to basically do all of the steps above.
However we still get an installation prompt from the downloaded APK itself.

- Is there any way to skip this installation prompt?
- Is there any way to say "Give us the rights to download and install more APKs" without the user need to do anything?

The code for installing the **APK**:

```
final File file = new File(apkPath);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY + ".provider", file);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_INSTALLED);
```

**Android Permissions:**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

The path we download the tmp-apk file to and installation source:

```
  String destination = this.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/";
```

**We understand that there are security restrictions**, but our solution would be for certain partners and they could provide us with a system signed apk. However, we tried with a system signed APK and we still got the installation prompt.

FYI: Our app runs on AndroidTV.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this your application (Launcher or your app which you're using to install other apps) should be the "Device Owner" which I'm guessing it is. Or it should be installed inside the System directory to use this permission.

You'll be needing to add this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

And then when you have your .apk file ready, do this

```
    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
    params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
    // set params
    try {
        int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
        PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
        OutputStream out = session.openWrite("COSU", 0, -1);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, c);
        }
        session.fsync(out);
        in.close();
        out.close();

        session.commit(createIntentSender(context, sessionId));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where **in** is your **InputFileSeream object**.

To convert your file into InputFileStream do this

```
new FileInputStream(apk_file)
```